# How zip file with encryption from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, zip

I want to zip files in `bash` script with password and I need to send password when zip prompt for pass and verification.

Here is code and it still asks for pass and pass_confirm:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=.
for i in $DIRECTORY/*.tar; do
  echo 'mypassword' | zip -0 -e $i'.zip' $i;
done
```

How send pass from script to zip command?

Comment: How to zip files and how to enter passwords has been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer.

Comment: Please read my question more attentively. I ask how to zip with encryption with password from bash script. Not just make pass protected zip. I need "echo" password and confirm to prompt when zip ask for them.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the real problem here is that OP doesn't understand why `-P` is considered insecure.

> ```
>   -P password
>   --password password
>          Use password to encrypt zipfile entries (if any).   THIS  IS  INSECURE!
>          Many  multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the
>          current command line of any other user;  even  on  stand-alone  systems
>          there  is  always the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking.  Storing the
>          plaintext password as part of a command line in an automated script  is
>          even worse.  Whenever possible, use the non-echoing, interactive prompt
>          to enter passwords.  (And where security is truly important, use strong
>          encryption  such  as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively weak
>          standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.)
> ```

To summarise, the two reasons for it being considered insecure, is that other users of the system may be able to see your executed commands and that people in the room may be able to see your password on the screen. What your attempt completely misses is that ***"Storing the plaintext password as part of a command line in an automated script  is even worse."***

From a security point of view, there is absolutely no difference between:

```
echo 'mypassword' | zip -e "$i.zip" $i
```

and

```
zip -e "$i.zip" $i -P 'mypassword'
```

In both cases, your password is part of the command and in both cases you are storing your password in plaintext in a script.

What you need is for your script to handle your password securely:

```
password=$(get_password_in_secure_manner)
zip -e "$i.zip" $i -P $password
```

As you might realise `get_password_in_secure_manner` isn't a real command unless you implement it. It's just a placeholder for what you might do to get the password into your script securely.

In summary, `-P` isn't inherently insecure, it just facilitates insecure behaviour. It also facilitates scripting, which is what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out it should work.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=.
for i in $DIRECTORY/*.tar; do
zip -0 -e $i'.zip' $i -P mypassword
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but for security reasons i want use -e

Comment: I have used -e and -P together and they work as well. -e is for encryption and -P is for provided password.

Comment: In than case  password for -P used for -e  encryption ?

Comment: No, the encryption is generic and it is independent of the password you provide. Both are different things.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily encrypt and decrypt ZIP files from the Linux command line without being prompted for the password. You can use the -P argument.

```
zip -P passw0rd secure.zip file
zip -P passw0rd secure.zip file1 file2 file3
```

> Also note that the standard ZIP encryption is very weak and could be
>   cracked easily.

Comment: Yes i know about -P and for security reasons want to encrypt with -e.
Thanks